# Joining list of data frames in R

Tags: r, list, join, dataframe, plyr

I have this example data

```
list_1<-list(data.frame(c(1:10)),data.frame(c(11:20)))
list_2<-list(data.frame(c(21:30)),data.frame(c(31:40)))
```

And I need to join them together to get structure like

```
list_3<-list(data.frame(c(1:10)),data.frame(c(11:20)),data.frame(c(21:30)),data.frame(c(31:40)))
```

It means that I have to create one new list of frames. Because when I use

```
list_3<-list(list_1,list_2)
```

then the first frame in list_1 is list_3[[1]][[1]] and it is problem for me. I need to call this frame like `list_3[[1]]`.
Any straightforward way how to achieve it?
I have tried some plyr like join, join_all and I cannot still done this.

Comment: `c(list_1,list_2)`....?

Comment: Or use `append(list_1, list_2)`

Comment: My godness. Thank you, my shortsideness

Comment: FYI, you don't need `c()` if you just want a sequence like `1:10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving some comments to the correct place (answers), the two most common solutions would be:

```
c(list_1, list_2)
```

or

```
append(list_1, list_2)
```

---

Since you had already tried:

```
list(list_1, list_2)
```

and found that this had created a nested `list`, you can also `unlist` the nested `list` with the argument `recursive = FALSE`.

```
unlist(list(list_1, list_2), recursive = FALSE)
```